# How to record a call in Windows Nokia Lumia 520?

Tags: 8.0, lumia

How to record incoming/outgoing calls in nokia lumia 520? Even 3rd party apps not supporting this feature.

Answer (score 5):

You can't record a call on Windows Phone devices. Neither built-in, nor third-party. Note that recording a telephone call is [illegal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_recording_laws) in many places.

Comment: Perhaps, but all my previous phones had this option.

Answer (score 4):

It is  currently not possible with third party apps,  but it could be possible with a third party app using the VoIP APIs. Once voice data is routed through another endpoint, like [Twilio](http://twilio.com), they could do whatever they wanted with the voice stream including recording it.

While the other answer includes it maybe illegal in some instances, it may be a legal requirement in another, like call center recording or other business functions.

Comment: It should be noted, that once you use Twilio or another service like that, you are not initiating the call on the phone - let alone you won't be able to handle call directed to the mobile phone number as long as you do not redirect them to the service which calls you back again (you shouldn't redirect that service again). This approach - while sometimes handy - might not be an end user approach in terms of comfort or costs.

Comment: Twilio is a service that is an end to a means. There are VOIP apis built into the phone. Twilio is a VOIP backend that any developer could use. The reason why I brought them up is because it is possible to build the app that was requested, using their service.